# How do I get the sum of an object property in a list

Tags: dart

```
 List<Cart> CARTLIST = [
    Cart(productName: "productName", amount: 123, image: "image", quantity: 3, desc: "KG", prodId: 1),
    Cart(productName: "productName", amount: 345, image: "image", quantity: 3, desc: "KG", prodId: 1),
  ];
```

How to get cart amount total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do:

```dart
var result = 0;
for (var cart in CARTLIST) {
  result += cart.amount;
}
```

It's short, direct and readable.

If you insist on doing it in a single expression, you can do:

```dart
var result = CARTLIST.fold<int>(0, (acc, cart) => acc + cart.amount);
```

Or you can do it in more steps, first extract the amounts, then add them up:

```dart
var result = CARTLIST.map((cart) => cart.amount).reduce((v1, v2) => v1 + v2);
```